# Why does the console giving Error: Cannot import an empty path?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><img alt="no photo" src="" /></div>

    <script>
      const myImage = document.querySelector("img");

      let myReq = new Request("903178.jpg");

      fetch(myReq)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response); //*no output in console*
          return response.blob();
        })
        .then(response => {
          let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(response);
          myImage.src = objectURL;
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> I have fetched image from same folder to render on html page but the error is showning in the console
>
> Error: Cannot import an empty path
>   CodeSandBox Link  - https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-river-re84i?file=/index.html

Comment: Is the network tab showing the image is in the correct path?

Comment: I don't get this error, with the exact HTML you provided. Please show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also check if maybe there is additional information next to the error you saw, such as a stack trace or filename and line number.

Comment: This error actually happens when you call `require('')` from inside https://codesandbox.io/, so I think you are not showing the full picture here. If it does happen inside codesandbox.io, why not giving us a link your test there?

Answer (score 2):

Based on codesandbox code that you provided, the issue is that you are adding an empty src="" in your image. All you need to do to get the code working is to either not give it initial src or put something in it like `src="#"`

```
<body>
<div><img alt="no photo" /></div>

<script>
  const myImage = document.querySelector("img");
  let myReq = new Request("903178.jpg");

  fetch(myReq)
    .then(response => {
      return response.blob();
    })
    .then(response => {
      let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(response);
      myImage.src = objectURL;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: [https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-river-re84i?file=/index.html](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-river-re84i?file=/index.html) codesandbox link

Comment: I edited my answer for you above. Please accept it when you change your codesandbox and see everything working. Make sure to click refresh button in codesandbox